# do objects that use the default spring-security user and hibernate need a custom user implementation

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a basic spring security login/logout setup working,
I have an object MyObject that has an attribute created_by with the user_id of the user who created the object. I also got the REST call working so that I get the object of the user who is currently calling the list function as attribute.

What I now want to do is filter on objects created by the user_id. For hibernate to work with this I think I have to have the User defined inside the objects created_by attribute since hibernate works with the entities.

e.g.:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User created_by; 
    ... 
}
```

But when I now list all MyObject objects I get:

```
 org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

I tried using @OneToMany on the created_by member but then i get:

```
 MyObject.created_by references an unknown entity: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

Since it works without the user entry there should be some problem with the serialization of the user object. I regenerated the serial_IDs of the other objects to be sure but the problem persists. Is there something that I missed or isn't this possible and I need to implement a custom user to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't come with any JPA support, so you must do your own User entity if you want query on user properties. If you only need to query on the username, you can do this shortcut:

```java
@Column
private String created_by;
```